# Hash Table Dynamical Resizing

Tags: algorithms, hash-function

I read the concept about dynamical resizing hash table from this [lecture](https://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.006/spring11/rec/rec07.pdf).
And for my understanding, it claims that the average run time of all insertions is $O(1)$ for **each iteration**.

Now, suppose we try to handle $n$ consecutive insertions and $n$ is not know in advance, so there might be several resizing before we finishing all the insertions.

In this case, is the average run time of all insertions still $O(1)$?

Answer (score 0):

Yes; as done in the lecture you have linked, this is shown using amortized analysis. The intuition is that even though resizing take $O(m)$ (where $m$ is the size of the table at the time of resizing), this operation occurs more infrequently the more times we have already resized.

Even if $n$ is not known in advance, as is the case in most practical applications of hashtables, the same amortized analysis holds. This is a simple result of the fact that in the analysis, the cost of the resize operation is divided among all insertions which occurred *before* the resizing operation. Hence, every time we resize the table, we have already achieved our $O(1)$ average runtime by the analysis provided. Any additional insertions we perform before the next resize will of course each be done in $O(1)$ time, so on average, each of the $n$ insertions takes $O(1)$ time.